# if a function f is $C^1$ and its derivative is bounded and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ converges then $f(x)\overset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, improper-integrals

> If a function $f \in C^1$  with bounded derivative and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ converges then $f(x)\overset{x\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}0$

I'm trying to prove this, intuitively, one might that f must go to zero otherwise the integral doesn't converge though it's incorrect.
I thought about comparing in some domain the anti derivative with its derivative though I am not sure why should f converge.

Comment: This is an easy consequence of the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343375/show-fx-to-0-as-x-to-infty

Comment: how do you know it's non negative?

Comment: The argument in that answer can be applied to $|f|$. The fact that $|f|$ is unifrmly continuous follows by MVT and you don't require differentiability of $\|f|$ for the proof.

Comment: how do we know that the integral on |f| converges?

Comment: You may use $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx=0$

Comment: @Caffeine do you have a proof for this?

Comment: Peru's objection is fair, right? If $f(x)= \sin(x) \sum_{n=1} 1_{[n2\pi,(n+1)2\pi)}\cdot \frac{1}{n},$ then $f$ admits an improper Riemann integral, but $|f|$ does not?

Comment: @peru Since $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^n f(x)$ converges the sequence $a_n:=\int_0^nf(x)dx$ is a Cauchy sequence

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Yes, my thought exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $f$ did not go to $0$. Then, there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n\to\infty$ and $|f(x_n)|\geq \varepsilon$. By thinning the sequence, the signs of $f(x_n)$ can be chosen equal so without loss of generality, $f(x_n)\geq \varepsilon$.

Let $M>0$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq M$ for all $x$ and note that $|f(x+\delta)-f(x)|\leq M\delta$ for all $\delta>0$ and $x\geq 0$ by the mean value theorem. Thus, we have that $f(y)\geq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for all $y\in [x_n, x_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}]$.
 Accordingly
$$
\left|\int_0^{x_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}} f(x)\textrm{d}x-\int_0^{x_n} f(x)\textrm{d}x\right|= \int_{x_n}^{x_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}} f(x)\textrm{d}x\geq \frac{\varepsilon^2}{4M}
$$

Thus, if $y_{2n-1}=x_n$ and $y_{2n}=x_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$, we get that $y_n\to \infty$ but $\left(\int_0^{y_n} f(x)\textrm{d}x\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is not Cauchy, and thus, the integral is not convergent.